# How could I obtain some possible permutations of a string of characters using Python?

Tags: python, string, permutation

I would like to write a Python code to be able to obtain some of the possible permutations of a string of characters.

I present two examples to show what I would like to do.

Example 1: Let's say that I have a string of characters that I write

```
my_list=['1','2','3','4']
```

What I would like to obtain are the 3 possible permutations starting the pairing from the left, meaning

```
['1', '2', '3','4'], ['1', '3', '2', '4'], ['1', '4', '2', '3']
```

So, the first value `'1'` can be paired with `'2'` or `'3'` or `'4'`, and then the remaining pair is `'3'`,`'4'` or `'2'`,`'4'` or `'2'`,`'3'`.

Example 2: Let's say that I have a string of characters that I write

```
my_list=['1','2','3','4','5','6']
```

What I would like to obtain are the 15 possible permutations starting the pairing from the left, meaning

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'],
['1', '2', '3', '5', '4', '6'],
['1', '2', '3', '6', '4', '5'],
['1', '3', '2', '4', '5', '6'],
['1', '3', '2', '5', '4', '6'],
['1', '3', '2', '6', '4', '5'],
['1', '4', '2', '3', '5', '6'],
['1', '4', '2', '5', '3', '6'],
['1', '4', '2', '6', '3', '5'],
['1', '5', '2', '3', '4', '6'],
['1', '5', '2', '4', '3', '6'],
['1', '5', '2', '6', '3', '4'],
['1', '6', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
['1', '6', '2', '4', '3', '5'],
['1', '6', '2', '5', '3', '4']
```

Where again we have the same kind of pairing as for the first example.

I would also like to obtain the possible permutations of longer strings (8, 10, ...). I would like to use Python because a string of 8 characters leads to 105 possible permutations when starting pairing from the left. Of course, I would like a single code that could give me these permutations for a string of arbitrary length.

The first example is not that difficult but I struggle a lot for the second example. For the first example, I tried using pairs of characters. I define my_list and then another list for the first pair. Then, I remove from my_list the first pair and the resulting string is given by concatenating the first pair and the remaining of my_list. Here is the code for the first example:

```
my_list_a = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
my_list_b = ['2', '3', '4']

for i in range(1,len(my_list_b)+1):
    tmp_list=['2', '3', '4']
    c = [my_list_a[0],my_list_a[i]]
    tmp_list.remove(my_list_a[i])
    print(c+tmp_list)
```

I tried to adapt this code for the second example but without success so far. I have seen that to deal with permutations we can use itertools but I did not manage to use it for my purpose.

Comment: What exactly is meant by starting pairing from the left?

Comment: It's very unclear what types of permutations you want to obtain. There are many more permutations for the two examples given...

Comment: @Unmitigated What I mean by pairing from the left is that I start with the first element (on the left) and pair it with another element of the string (on the right). This is why I don't have the permutation `['1', '3', '4', '2']` for example.

Comment: @Téo Maybe it's clearer with figures 1 and 4 of this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.08849.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Simple recursion with still available values and already built partial output:

```py
def pair(unpaired, paired=[]):
    if not unpaired:
        print(paired)
    for i in range(len(unpaired) - 1):
        first, *rest = unpaired
        pair(rest, paired + [first, rest.pop(i)])

pair(['1','2','3','4','5','6'])
```

Output ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RU_LCsIwELz3K_aWrKZCfSFCv6T0UGiiAdmEND34LV560X_y7I-YNH0MDAuzu8PM62Of_m5oGN69V_nl-2ulAttox3uKQ7YC0iyrGq8ZBGgFZDzMB0mMsE6T50nFUVXGgQZN4Bq6Sf6QtPgi5FDg-qy067yAjZOdh3JxX81jqLicA8EWqukpyjtrLNdYY5aNpxUrmGD7wEPgMfAUeGY1pqpT47n5Hw)):

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
['1', '2', '3', '5', '4', '6']
['1', '2', '3', '6', '4', '5']
['1', '3', '2', '4', '5', '6']
['1', '3', '2', '5', '4', '6']
['1', '3', '2', '6', '4', '5']
['1', '4', '2', '3', '5', '6']
['1', '4', '2', '5', '3', '6']
['1', '4', '2', '6', '3', '5']
['1', '5', '2', '3', '4', '6']
['1', '5', '2', '4', '3', '6']
['1', '5', '2', '6', '3', '4']
['1', '6', '2', '3', '4', '5']
['1', '6', '2', '4', '3', '5']
['1', '6', '2', '5', '3', '4']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried recursion but I struggle to understand it so I was stuck with this problem for a long time...

Comment: Do you know how I could store each of the permutations and return them as output? I tried to use return in different places but the best I could get was the last possibility... Maybe using an array `solutions` and a `count` variable to put the `paired` in `solutions[count]`? So far I have not succeeded in doing it...

Comment: @User3000 You can do `solutions = []` beforehand and replace `print(paired)` with `solutions.append(paired)`.

Answer (score -1):

Updated my answer with the correct solution after feedback from the author.

```
a = ['1','2','3','4','5','6']

def get_pairs(a, exc_val: int = None):

    if exc_val is not None:
        a = a[:exc_val] + a[exc_val+1:]

    if len(a) <=2:
        return [a]
    
    a0 = a.pop(0)
    t = [[a0, k] + b  for i, k in enumerate(a) for b in get_pairs(a,i)]
    return t

get_pairs(a)
```

Comment: This does not produce the intended answer for `['1','2','3','4','5', '6']`.

Comment: It's very similar to what I want to obtain but some of the permutations are not wanted. For the second example, a lot of them are not wanted.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an algorithm for your task:

```py
def generate_permutations_left(input_list):
    permutations = [input_list.copy()]  # Include the original list

    for i in range(1, len(input_list) - 1):
        # Swap elements and save the list
        input_list[i], input_list[i + 1] = input_list[i + 1], input_list[i]
        permutations.append(input_list.copy())

        # Back to original order
        input_list[i], input_list[i + 1] = input_list[i + 1], input_list[i]

    return permutations
```

In each iteration it swaps the current element with the next element in the list, then it saves that modified list, finally it sets back the original order.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But for the first example, I get the solution `['1', '2', '4', '3']` instead of `['1', '4', '2', '3']`

Comment: You can just declare the `permutations` as `[]` instead of `[input_list.copy()]`